# Can I create a new syntax in C++?

Tags: c++11, macros, iterator, generator

I am quite fond of Python generator expression and (ab)use it a lot in Python. Now I am (up to no good) working on implementing generator expression on C++ 11, using macros embedded in macros, lambdas and more obscure things. My aim is to copy all abilities of operator as close as possible. There are some implementations already, but they lack multi-variable support.
Python most complex syntax looks like

```
generator = i*j for i,j in zip(arr1,arr2) if i>0 and j>0 # Python
```

This line produces a functor that returns on every successfull call a multiplication of repective values from two arrays. And in my realization syntax now looks like

```
auto generator = brf_genexpr(i*j,(i,j),zip(arr1, arr2),i>0 && j>0); //C++11
```

My question is: do you know some way, however exotic, to get rid of those lots of commas and allow me to write

```
auto generator = brf_genexpr(i*j for i,j in zip(arr1,arr2) if (i>0 && j>0));
```

I do understand that I can write a preprocessor script that would change syntax for me, but I would love a in-code solution.
*Updates:*

- My question is only about the call syntax, my implementation is working already.

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: You can somehow achieve similar results with functors with state (i.e. classes that overload `operator()` and keep track of their state)

Comment: That is how I do it. I use macros to minimize syntax, lambdas for filter and combine expressions, and functor with both () and iterators as a result value. Wouldn't even think about it without C++11.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino well there was that guy here who left on a quest to implement lambdas in C. Wonder where he is now.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is completely impossible to use language keywords (`for`, `if`) in new ways.

If you're willing to use different tokens (such as 'genfor`,`genif`), then something will be possible.